# running shell command using python subprocess

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

why python's subprocess.Popen() behavior is odd when running shell command as string and as list? when should we pass shell command as string and as list?

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> p = subprocess.Popen('du -sh *', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
>>> stdout, _ = p.communicate()
>>> print stdout[:1000]
244M    bin
3.1M    bmps
14M     buildweb
10M     contrib
4.0M    gobuild
168K    gobuild-starter-kit
468K    gobuild-test
3.6M    lib
46M     machines
1.4M    machineweb
75M     microservices
1.4M    monthly_maintenance
20K     perforce
9.1M    scheduler
196K    service
2.5M    statusweb
516K    storage
228K    symindex
7.2M    webapps

>>> p = subprocess.Popen('du -sh *'.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
>>> stdout, _ = p.communicate()
>>> print stdout[:1000]
8       ./statusweb/infrastructure/management/commands
12      ./statusweb/infrastructure/management
16      ./statusweb/infrastructure
48      ./statusweb/statusweb/settings
56      ./statusweb/statusweb
164     ./statusweb/dashboard/migrations
8       ./statusweb/dashboard/tests/fixtures
64      ./statusweb/dashboard/tests
12      ./statusweb/dashboard/static/dashboard/img
12      ./statusweb/dashboard/static/dashboard/css
48      ./statusweb/dashboard/static/dashboard/js/status
12      ./statusweb/dashboard/static/dashboard/js/spec
72      ./statusweb/dashboard/static/dashboard/js
100     ./statusweb/dashboard/static/dashboard
104     ./statusweb/dashboard/static
36      ./statusweb/dashboard/templates/dashboard/dust
32      ./statusweb/dashboard/templates/dashboard/emails
88      ./statusweb/dashboard/templates/dashboard
8       ./statusweb/dashboard/templates/admin/dashboard/issue
8       ./statusweb/dashboard/templates/admin/dashboard/maintenance
20      ./statusweb/dashboard/templates/admin/dashboard
28      ./statusweb/dashboard/templates/admin
8       ./statusweb/dashboard/templates/registra
```

Answer (score 2):

When you pass in a list only the first item is treated as a command. The rest is treated as arguments to the shell used to run the command. From the  [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) :

> On POSIX with shell=True, the shell defaults to /bin/sh. If args is a
>   string, the string specifies the command to execute through the shell.
>   This means that the string must be formatted exactly as it would be
>   when typed at the shell prompt. This includes, for example, quoting or
>   backslash escaping filenames with spaces in them. If args is a
>   sequence, the first item specifies the command string, and any
>   additional items will be treated as additional arguments to the shell
>   itself. That is to say, Popen does the equivalent of:
>
> `Popen(['/bin/sh', '-c', args[0], args[1], ...])`